# 'Du' command does not list all files

Tags: bash, find, du

I receive different number of files with `du -h` and `find`:

```
loom@loom-desktop$ du -h ~/storage/Apps/*/trunk/test/*.cpp | wc -l
35
loom@loom-desktop$ find ~/storage/Apps/ -path */trunk/test/*.cpp | wc -l
111
```

What is the reason of the mismatch and how to list all files with corresponding sizes in the given constraints?

Comment: Remove the pipe and "wc" and save the files, then diff them to see what's up.

Comment: They are clearly different, as the first will only look one directory deep and the other will go down to any depth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for `globstar`.  Say:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

and say:

```
du -h ~/storage/Apps/**/trunk/test/*.cpp    # note ** after Apps
```

Quoting from the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching):

> `*`
>
> Matches any string, including the null string. When the globstar shell
>   option is enabled, and `‘*’` is used in a filename expansion context,
>   two adjacent `‘*’`s used as a single pattern will match all files and
>   zero or more directories and subdirectories. If followed by a `‘/’`, two
>   adjacent `‘*’`s will match only directories and subdirectories.